# is char really bad in modern C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm doing a C programming exercise, but I have some problems with declarations. I read I shouldn't use **char** declaration type, but I should use **int** instead (according to https://matt.sh/howto-c I should use neither of them). Working code with *unwanted* **char**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{

int hour_12, min;
char ch, ch2;

printf("What time is it? (in xx:xx PM format): ");
scanf("%d:%d %c%c", &hour_12, &min, &ch, &ch2);

printf("%c%c\n", ch, ch2); /* just a checkpoint */

if (ch == 'P' && ch2 == 'M' || ch == 'p' && ch2 == 'p'){
    if (hour_12 != 12){
        printf("Hour_12: %d:%d %c%c\n", hour_12, min, ch, ch2);
        printf("Hour_24: %d:%d\n", hour_12 + 12, min);
    }
    else{
        printf("Hour_12: %d:%d %c%c\n", hour_12, min, ch, ch2);
        printf("Hour_24: %d:%d\n", hour_12, min);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Problem number 1:

when using ‘**int** ch, ch2;’ program ignores the check on line 15:

```
if (ch == 'P' && ch2 == 'M' || ch == 'p' && ch2 == 'p'){  […]  }
```

and the result is just 'PM' from:

```
printf("%c%c\n", ch, ch2); /* just a checkpoint */
```

Problem number 2:

when using ‘**uint8_t** ch, ch2;’ program won’t assign provided number to very first „%d” → ‘hour_12’ from line 11:

```
scanf("%d:%d %c%c", &hour_12, &min, &ch, &ch2);
```

and ‘hour_12’ is always 0:

> PM
>
> Hour_12: 0:11 PM
>
> Hour_24: 12:11

Is there any way to solve this without **char**? Or perhaps **char** isn't bad at all? I would like to learn good programming practices, but it seems it's very hard to find up-to-date books. I own K. N. King second edition C programming, but I've experienced some undefined program behavior at least twice when following it. I'm using GCC version 10.0.1 20200325 (Red Hat 10.0.1-0.10).

Regards.

Comment: Looks like what you were reading was an over-simplification.  `char` is perfectly fine to use to hold characters.

Comment: You use `int c;` for those functions that can return `EOF`, which is defined as -1. All 8 bits of a char are used to denote an ASCII character, so -1 cannot be represented in a char.

Comment: Why would a char type be bad?  No, I didn't open the link because my oven-mitt facepalm protection is too worn.

Comment: Perhaps more relevant is that many new C coders use `char` where they should be using `int`. There are very few standard library functions that either take `char` argument or return that type. Also the standard library functions are not written with `uint32_t` etc.

Comment: For those who don't want to click the link, it is promoting the use of `stdint.h` types and saying all other integer types should never be used in new code.  It also has wrong opinions about what `char` is.

Comment: In fairness, the author's "one exception to never-char" covers exactly the use case here: a "pre-existing API" (here `scanf`).  But it seems to me that this is an exception that swallows the rule.

Comment: Here's a gem from the link, claiming that the `int_leastXX_t` types are exactly the same as the `intXX_t` types: "*The least guidelines, in practice, mean least types are just defined to standard fixed width types, since standard fixed width types already provide the exact minimum number of bits you request.*"  Seems like the author doesn't truly understand the implications of `stdint.h` types.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I think he just means that *in practice*, on many common implementations, `int_least32_t` is the same type as `int32_t`.  Which is indeed often true.  You would certainly not want to rely on it being true, and I don't think he's saying you should.

Comment: @NateEldredge The problem is that it is factually wrong.  For people like us who know better, we understand where he's coming from and what it actually means, but for others who could actually stand to learn from an article about `stdint.h` types, it's simply misinformation.  If it provides misinformation to people don't already understand the library, then what good is the article?  Especially as it combines opinion along with the misinformation.  In my opinion, it is an irresponsible article.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the code presented here.  The use of `char` is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

@WilliamPursell

Care to elaborate? I hope you doesn't mean its incompleteness?

Answer (score 1):

You need to critically think about all statements you encounter, including this one. When someone says that the type of `char` is *bad*, your natural question should be

> why?

Whoever makes such a statement should give a

- convincing
- testable
- detailed

explanation to this question. I did not read the link, so I do not know the exact reasoning, but if you find it convincing, then edit your question, add the reasoning and let me know about it.

Now, if you are convinced that `char` is *bad* indeed, then your next question should be

> in what case is char bad?

It might well be that there is some conditional rule and, when the given condition is true, then that's indeed the case. When you automatically ask yourself the skeptical questions that protect you from believing in mistaken statements, then you will start to get more mature as a programmer.

Your

```
if (ch == 'P' && ch2 == 'M' || ch == 'p' && ch2 == 'p'){  […]  }
```

criteria is not ignored. It's just false in the case you have mentioned. Ask yourself the right questions again:

> What do I want to achieve this code? Can I translate the condition
>   above into a plain English question?

Well, the answer should be either a strong "no", or a weak "yes". A strong "no", if you do not understand it. A weak "yes" if you understand, or think you understand it now. Let's attempt to formulate the statement in plain words:

> If ch is 'P' and ch2 is 'M' or ch is 'p' and ch2 is 'p'.

Note that without the or, this statement would always be false, because contradicting values are checked against ch2. So, let's see what the operator precedence is here. Looking here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

you see that logical AND has a precedence of 11 and logical OR has a precedence of 12. Let's make this explicit, to avoid having to think about operator precedences:

```
if ((ch == 'P' && ch2 == 'M') || (ch == 'p' && ch2 == 'p')){  […]  }
```

How can we formulate this into plain words:

ch is 'P' and ch2 is 'M', or both of them is 'p'.

So, you will need to check what the actual values of your variables are. In the case of char, it works, if I'm not mistaken. Otherwise, you need to check what the values are and compare them against the corresponding type representation of the given characters. It's counter-intuitive, unless you work out a clear representation.

Comment: Thank you very much for such comprehensive reply! I concentrated on mentioned 'char' 'problem' and I've missed other things. I'll do my best to better understand the topic and improve. I like your methodology very much.

Comment: @Pawel523 you are welcome. Remember, your own thoughts should always counterbalance surprising claims. If you cannot find, no matter how hard you try reasons to believe a claim, then trust your own reasoning and be skeptical. But, on the other hand, be convincable with good arguments. This kind of sensibility to truth, whatever it is will help you very much on the long run.